# Phonegap blackberry sign application issue

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

I have created blackberry project and follow the [instructions](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html) on the PhoneGap site.

I have used ripple emulator for build the application .Package was created and build successfully, but when I try to package and sign it it shows this error:

> -Oh Snap! Build request failed with message: [ERROR] Cannot sign application - failed to find signing key file: barsigner.csk

When I used package-launch it installed in emulator and launched the application, but it only showed blank screen.

Can someone please help me find what I am missing and help me manually sign the application?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](http://inflagrantedelicto.memoryspiral.com/2011/02/blackberry-playbook-code-signing-process/) guide for signing BlackBerry applications? You might want to take a look at [this](http://andreas-schrade.de/2012/02/a-nightmare-signing-apps-for-blackberry-app-world/) one also.

Comment: I'll link also the [official guide](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/signing_setup.html) on signing webworks apps.

Comment: It is necessary to sign the application to deploy in simulator ?

Comment: Not getting actual process here ...i follow the process which to filled order form and i got 3 different file of .csi .i wasregister with command prompt with this command -                                .java -jar SignatureTool.jar client-RRT-2064114.csi ..now what abt csk file i dont received any csk file here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Build Projectt :build project :navigate to project folder and cmd
  command  : ant blackberry build
- Register with server : blackberry-signer -register -csjpin ***123
  -cskpass** @123 client-RDK-20***.csj
- sign app : blackberry-signer -storepass ***@123 test.bar
- install app : blackberry-deploy -installApp -password ***@123 -device
  192.***.***.*** -package test.bar  -password ***@123 ((Navigate to sdk path bin folder under dependency ))

  Ref site : http://inflagrantedelicto.memoryspiral.com/2011/02/blackberry-playbook-code-signing-process/